# Give each row of files in a list unique IDs

Tags: r, list, mapply

I have a number of files, and I need to give each one a unique ID code automatically.

So far, I have managed to do the following:

```
datalist <- mapply(cbind, datalist, "temp1"=names(datalist), SIMPLIFY=F)
```

which puts the name of the file into a new column.

But then I want to add in a number, from 1:number of rows in each file.

I have tried a couple of things, but I didn't really expect either to work:
(I was then going to paste them together and delete the 'temp' columns - then figure out how to do it in one step without the temp columns):

```
datalist <- mapply(cbind, datalist, "temp2"=1:(sapply(datalist, nrow)), SIMPLIFY=F)
```

or

```
datalist <- mapply(cbind, datalist, "temp2"=1:nrow(datalist), SIMPLIFY=F)
```

I can get the number of rows for a single bit of the list (`nrow(datalist[[1]])`), but am unsure how to apply that to all of them, regardless of how many are in the list.

Is it a for loop, or is there a better way?

Example dataset:

```
datalist <- structure(list(test.raw.data = structure(list(officer.sw = c("bob", 
NA, "brian", "brian", NA), officer.ne = c(NA, "angie", NA, NA, 
NA), officer.nw = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "lola")), .Names = c("officer.sw", 
"officer.ne", "officer.nw"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), test2.raw.data = structure(list(officer.sw = c("bob", 
"NA", "brian", "brian", "NA", "bob", "NA", "bob", "bob", "NA", 
"NA"), officer.ne = c("NA", "angie", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"sandy", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), officer.nw = c("NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "lola", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "lola", "NA"), officer.EM = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "mr bendy"
), randomothercol = c("angie", "b", "c", "e", "d", "fg", "t", 
"wsefg", "aweg", "lola", "g")), .Names = c("officer.sw", "officer.ne", 
"officer.nw", "officer.EM", "randomothercol"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))), .Names = c("test.raw.data", "test2.raw.data"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
makeIndex <- function(x, name, sep="-"){
  cbind(index=paste(name, seq_along(x[[1]]), sep=sep), x)
}

lapply(seq_along(datalist), function(i)makeIndex(datalist[[i]], names(datalist)[i]))
```

The result:

```
[[1]]
            index officer.sw officer.ne officer.nw
1 test.raw.data-1        bob       <NA>       <NA>
2 test.raw.data-2       <NA>      angie       <NA>
3 test.raw.data-3      brian       <NA>       <NA>
4 test.raw.data-4      brian       <NA>       <NA>
5 test.raw.data-5       <NA>       <NA>       lola

[[2]]
               index officer.sw officer.ne officer.nw officer.EM randomothercol
1   test2.raw.data-1        bob         NA         NA         NA          angie
2   test2.raw.data-2         NA      angie         NA         NA              b
3   test2.raw.data-3      brian         NA         NA         NA              c
4   test2.raw.data-4      brian         NA         NA         NA              e
5   test2.raw.data-5         NA         NA       lola         NA              d
6   test2.raw.data-6        bob         NA         NA         NA             fg
7   test2.raw.data-7         NA      sandy         NA         NA              t
8   test2.raw.data-8        bob         NA         NA         NA          wsefg
9   test2.raw.data-9        bob         NA         NA         NA           aweg
10 test2.raw.data-10         NA         NA       lola         NA           lola
11 test2.raw.data-11         NA         NA         NA   mr bendy              g
```

Comment: Somehow, after testing both these answers, `names(datalist)` is now `NULL`... I still need the names of the list elements for later on, and I'm not eentirely sure why they are being deleted?

Comment: The names of your original `datalist` will only change if you assigned a new value to this object.  My solution does not change the original object.  If you wish, you can easily rename the result of my answer, i.e. by using `names(...) <- names(datalist)`

Comment: Thank you :)  yes I thought about just reassigning them last night after I went home.  Thank you for your help!  Don't know which of these answers to tick, they're both so similar!

Comment: I selected this response, simply because the ID column ended up with the same title for each dataframe, which was handy.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your original `datalist` at the bottom of your post, you could do some indexing inside an `lapply` call.

```
> lapply(seq(datalist), function(i) {
      datalist[[i]][[paste0("temp", i)]] <- 
          paste0(names(datalist)[i], seq(nrow(datalist[[i]])))
      datalist[[i]]
  })
# [[1]]
#   officer.sw officer.ne officer.nw          temp1
# 1        bob       <NA>       <NA> test.raw.data1
# 2       <NA>      angie       <NA> test.raw.data2
# ...
# 
# [[2]]
#    officer.sw officer.ne officer.nw officer.EM randomothercol            temp2
# 1         bob         NA         NA         NA          angie  test2.raw.data1
# 2          NA      angie         NA         NA              b  test2.raw.data2
# ...
```